# CSS Grid Layout with rows inside of columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been pulling my hair out over this for days. I'm trying to create a grid layout for a dynamic number of posts. The layout should be:

- Each row has 3 items
- First item: width: 65%, height 600px
- Second Item: width:35%, height 300px
- Third Item: width:35%, height 300px

So in this row, visually there are 2 columns, the first has 1 large item, the second has 2 smaller items stacked vertically one below the other.

Then, the next row should be the same, but reversed, i.e.

- First item: width: 35%, height 300px
- Second Item: width:35%, height 300px
- Third Item: width:65%, height 600px

...then the pattern repeats.

My hands are a bit constrained because I am modifying up a wordpress post widget, but here are my selectors:
The post container is .rn-portflio .elementor-grid which currently has this CSS:

```
.elementor-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}
```

Then, each item inside the container has the class .e-loop-item

Here is the CSS I have tried - this is the closest I have got.

```
.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n-5),
.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n-5) .elementor-section,
.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n) .elementor-section, 
.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n-5) .elementor-container, 
.rn-portfolio .e-loop-item:nth-of-type(6n-5) .elementor-container {
    height: 600px;
}
```

The result of this means that the first row is correct, then, the second row of items has 2 small items horizontally next to each other, and one large item directly below it, all in one column spanning 2/3 and the last 1/3 column is empty

Comment: The css code you're writing isn't formatted as a code, I can't read it. However, what I do understand is that you want a series of rows alternating their order (1st row - normal flow, 2nd row reverse flow, 3rd row normal flow,....) and each row is a set of one big column and two rows stacked in one column, right? If that what you want, you can do it using both flex and grid display. If you want a snippet of code demonstrating the solution, confirm with me my understanding of your problem.

Comment: Apologies - forgot to format the code! yes that is correct as you say it

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your solution. I made the row height here 300px just because the window here is small (you can make the row height 600px in your implementation)

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  margin:0; padding: 0;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.main{
  flex: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.side{
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second{
  flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
.third{
  flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="stacks-container">

<div class="row">
  <div class="main">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" >
  <div class="main">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row" >
  <div class="main">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" >
  <div class="main">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" >
  <div class="main">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="second">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    Third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Trial using Grid.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 150px);
  padding: 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: lightgray;
}

.cell:nth-child(6n + 1),
.cell:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-row: auto/span 2;
  grid-column: auto/span 2;
}


/*  try to modify the hardcoded 3 in the sixth
grid to get the previous grid row (auto -1) */

.cell:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-row: 3/ span 2;
  grid-column: 2/ span 2;
}

.cell:nth-child(6n + 2),
.cell:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: auto/span 1;
}

.cell:nth-child(6n + 4),
.cell:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  grid-row: auto/span 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="cell">
    First
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Second
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Third
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Fourth
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Fifth
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Sixth

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is my items aren't in row containers - they are just all items in one container - but could potentially use nth-child selectors to target the items in the second "row"??

Comment: @SamSkirrow So you're meaning that it's all divs in the container with no row divs like the following <div class='container'> <div> First </div>  <div> Second</div>  <div> Third</div>  </div>

Comment: Correct yes!!!!

Comment: @SamSkirrow I managed to do most of it, except for one cell (I don't the sixth cell, I don't know how to make its nth child dynamic because I can't get the current "auto" value and of the current row, I will modify the solution, take a look. If you can modify the hard coded grid-row: 3/ span 2; to something like grid-row: auto -1 / span 2. You'll have your solution.

Comment: @SamSkirrow lookup the second code snippet, if you managed to modify the line of code with the comment /*  try to modify the hardcoded 3 in the sixth grid*/
for the sixth grid repeated child, you can get your solution. because I can't get the current row number dynamically.